# How to create AVD's in android studio version 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

[image: I don't find any option to open for creating avd from below version of android studio, Please help]

I am using android studio from both windows-10 and mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are confusing AVD and SDK. AVD is a simulator which you use to run the project.

Create a project completely, after which goto Tools->Android->AVD manager, where you can create a custom AVD.

Comment: Yes, this helps. Basically i need not have to create new android projects since i am using it for test automation and with previous versions we had option to open from sdk manager itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1. Create some project in yours AS.
2. Find in top panel icon with next text: AVD Manager
3. Click on icon with text: AVD Manager - you'll see a dialog - in dialog find **Create Virtual Device**.